# How to edit tableview cell on TAP instead of swipe - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and at the moment, the user can swipe left on the cell to reveal an 'add to favourites' button. I would now like to add an icon to the cell that the user can tap to reveal the this button (does the same thing as swiping to the left). This will just act as a visual aid for the users who do not know swiping left will do the same thing.

For my `TableView`, I use the following code to 'close the cell' when the user has pressed the button:

```
itemsTableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

From this I assumed that to manually open the cell I would simply call:

```
//Get cell
let cell:TableViewCell = itemsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 
sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! TableViewCell 

//Open cell to reveal button
cell.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Unfortunately this does not work. So I would like to know what is the function that is called when a user swipes to the left of a cell and how can I replicate it when a user taps on the icon?

Comment: "what is the function that is called when a user swipes to the left of a cell and how can I replicate it when a user taps on the icon" You tell us that. You say the user can swipe left. You implemented that somehow. Well, how?

Comment: @matt I don't call anything. When I implement `tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to set my custom actions, this activates the 'swipe to edit' functionality. That's all I do. I'm expecting anyone who wants to add input to this question to already know that... If it were as simple as 'just call the function you are calling when a user swipes' I wouldn't be asking this question would I?

Comment: Don't get snippy. There are lots of other ways to do this; I needed to know that you are using `editActions...`. Now you've answered. That's the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You can mimic this behavior with a custom implementation. I've posted a snippet where this is done https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227225/1800915. Verified and works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do it, sorry. This feature relies on the UITableView's pan gesture recognizer. When the user pans sideways, the table view checks the `editActions...` delegate method and, if we have edit actions, inserts a private confirmation view behind the cell and allows the cell to be moved to reveal it. You can't trigger that behavior programmatically as far as I can tell.

This would be a reason — one of many very good reasons — for sticking with a third-party scrollable cell class. In this way, the cell is a horizontal scroll view and you just scroll it in code.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. No wonder I could't find a way to do it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I did a bunch of exploring with the View Debugger and LLDB to try to work out how this feature works, and that's all I came up with. If there were a scroll view here, we could try to scroll it in code, but there just isn't one (at least, not at any time while things are at rest).

Comment: Well thank you for the help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any update to this? I assume if one could find how the swipe action is triggered, they could put it inside didSelectRowAt.