# How to display swipe button in uitableviewcell by tap on cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tried to call the functions manually by programming, those functions are

```
    -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES; //tableview must be editable or nothing will work...
}
```

When i call the functions it works inside the functions for example the editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function but doesnt show the button.
Any clue or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Jato see my below answer

Comment: Thank you very much user3182145, but i want to display more button when i tap on the uitableviewcell. I just want to swipe and display button when i tap on uitableviewcell nothing more. I highly appreciate your time spend on the problem.

Comment: For more clear understanding i want to have clue to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332352/how-to-edit-tableview-cell-on-tap-instead-of-swipe-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forgot to call `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use above 3 methods for swipe and deleting the table view cell?
Only one method  is enough for doing this.I created sample one for your question.It works fine.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewEdit;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *arr;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewEdit;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"Android",@"Windows",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UITableViewDataSource methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return  arr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *strCell = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewEdit dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

When I run the application first it shows the below data

[image]

Then when I swipe the table view

[image]

Finally I delete the data from the table view and the table view

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much user3182145, but i want to display more button when i tap on the uitableviewcell. I just want to swipe and display button when i tap on uitableviewcell nothing more.

Comment: For more clear understanding i want to have clue to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332352/how-to-edit-tableview-cell-on-tap-instead-of-swipe-swift

Comment: I think you can't go more than this.

Comment: I statically created the data.Even it is helpful for dynamic data.