# How to trigger UITableViewCell editActions programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have made a few custom edit actions on my tableviewcell. It works fine when I swipe, but I was wondering if there was any way to trigger these actions when I tap the cell. Also, I have seen lots of people answer similar questions with just,

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

though this is not the solution I am looking for. I want the actions to immediately get displayed without the press of another button.

[image: This is what I mean by editActions]

Comment: It sounds like you should override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` - this method will get called when a cell is tapped, and you can call appropriate action then.

Comment: Apple has private API to do what you want, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically but remember that it's not recommended and your app could be rejected.

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro I have already seen the answer to that question and I have tried making it works in swift 4. When I run it it says 'NSInvalidArgumentException, setShowingDeleteConfirmationWithArg1 unrecognized selector'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is - there is no such way.

However, if you really need something like that, you can mimic this behaviour, though it requires lot more implementation and state handling on your own.

Here is a quick and very dirty solution, which overrides `touchesEnded` method of your custom cell. Remember to set up Cell as a dynamic prototype of the cell in your table view in relevant storyboard and set its reuse identifier to `identitifer`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier") as? Cell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        return nil
    }

    func doAction(for cell: Cell) {
        let indexPath = cell.indexPath
        print("doing action for cell at: \(indexPath!.row)")
        // your implementation for action
        // maybe delete a cell or whatever?
        cell.hideFakeActions()

    }

}

protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func doAction(for cell: Cell)
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonAction1: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet weak var constraintButtonFakeActionWidth: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.constraintButtonFakeActionWidth?.constant = 0
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                               with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {
            return
        }
        if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {

            print("event is in cell number \(indexPath.row)")
            self.showFakeActions()

        }
    }

    func showFakeActions() {
        self.constraintButtonFakeActionWidth?.constant = 80
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func hideFakeActions() {
        self.constraintButtonFakeActionWidth?.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func fakeAction() {
        delegate?.doAction(for: self)
    }
}
```

So how does it work? Each cell is a `UIView` which inherits from abstract `UIResponder` interface. You can override its methods to do actions on your own on behalf of events that are dispatched to them. This is the first step where you override `touchesEnded`.

Take a look at the screenshot from interface builder - you have to hook up the constraint.
[image]

I've also implemented the delegate which returns nil for all edit actions of the cells, so they don't interfere with your workaround.

Next, you set up a custom delegate to get a callback from the cell. I also attached IndexPath to the cell for the convenience of managing data in the dataSource, which you have to implement.

Remember that this code lacks a lot, like `prepareForReuse` method implementation. Also, you probably want to do additional checks in `touchesEnded` override which would guarantee that this delegate callback is not fired more than once per touch and prevent multiple touches. The logic for disabling user interaction on a cell is not implemented here as well. And interface requires fine-tuning (like text appears to be squashed during the animation).

Comment: Your code works though I am having a little trouble understanding how it answers my question. I may not have been clear enough, what I am trying to do is to display the editActions, like delete or more, when I tap on a cell.

Comment: lol, now after your update I understand what did you mean. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.